# How to Make Emacs Display Chinese Characters

Tags: emacs, non-ascii-characters, cjk

I often use simple Chinese phrases like "你好" to test that my code can handle non-ascii characters. Whenever I enter Chinese characters directly into Emacs, they just come out as question marks.

Emacs can sometimes display characters properly if I open a premade text file but not always. For example, if I create a simple text file in Notepad with "你好" in it, the 好 displays fine but 你 just shows a box. Can Emacs handle Chinese characters? If so, how do I set it up?

I'm running Emacs 22.3.1 on Windows with the Courier New font, but I'm also curious about having this work on Linux. I have all the needed Eastern Language packages installed. I can edit in Chinese in Notepad with no problem.

Comment: 1. What happens when you load a file with Chinese in it without manually typing it in?
2. Does Chinese display correctly in other software on your windows system?
3. Are you using a Chinese version of Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Emacs 23 release solves the problem I was having on Windows. Chinese characters work properly with no fussing or hacking. I can write Chinese directly in a buffer or open a file with no issues. Emacs's unicode support wasn't fully implemented until version 23.

[Emacs 23 Release Notes](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu-emacs/2009-07/msg00000.html)

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. I've copied the text from the question into a buffer and it displays correctly. v23.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this (leim)?
http://www.khngai.com/emacs/chinese.php

Answer (score 0):

Liberation Mono font, which I use under Emacs, can display these characters.